# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to create Country, State, city. There is no issue with Country and State table. But for City table I am getting 'Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed' error. I am using MySQL version 10.4.19

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Country` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Country` (
  `CountryId` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  `CountryName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CountryId`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`State` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`State` (
  StateId SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  `StateName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `CountryId` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (StateId),
    INDEX `fk_State_Country_idx` (`CountryId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_State_Country`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CountryId`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Country` (`CountryId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`City` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`City` (
  `CityId` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  `CityName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  StateId SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CityId),
    INDEX `fk_City_State1_idx` (StateId ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_City_State1`
    FOREIGN KEY (StateId)
    REFERENCES State (StateId)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: works fine for me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/293f00

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Some statements do not have `mydb` qualifier. Could be that MySQL is referencing the wrong table.

Comment: I faced same problem with mydb qualifier

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the tables already exist in the database and have FKs that are already related to other tables.

you have to eliminate them from the lowest relationship to the highest

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`City` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`State` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Country` ;
```

Comment: Tables don't exists. I dropped the schema. I solved the issue by changing table name from City to City1. I am clueless.